# probability calculation 2 vs 1

Tags: probability, bayesian

I got a little rusty with statistics.

My problem:

There are three labels: good, bad, ugly

For each instance there is a definite label, e.g Clint Eastwood is good, Eli Wallach is ugly.

When asking a random person on the street to identify the actors with labels, the chances for a proper identification is 70%.
E.g when asking 10 people, 7 will on avg say that Clint is good.

Now, if I show 3 persons a picture of Eli Wallach and 2 say it's X and 1 says it's Y. What is the probability that

- X = ugly
- Y = ugly

?

How do I write it as a formula?

Comment: You already said that the probability is 70%.

Comment: As far as I understand the chance for the 2 to have guessed it right is 67% -- meaning proba that 2 have it right, 1 wrong vs. 2 wrong and 1 right vs. all 3 wrong.

Comment: So you should clarify: are you asking if probability that any of them gets it right or all of them?

Comment: I'm asking what is the probability that X is ugly and Y is ugly respectively

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean..? Eli Wallach *is* "Ugly", so there is no probability it is a fact. Are you asking what is the probability that the guess is correct? In such a case, what is X and Y in your question? Could you give an actual example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly

Each of the three characters has a definite true label. (EW = ugly, CE = good, LVC = bad).

Each random person will be 70% accurate identifying them.

Question: 
If you ask 3 people on the street to identify EW (or CE or LVC), and 2 say one thing, while the third says something else -- what is the proba that the majority got the right label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have are the conditional probabilities *"when a person is shown the image of an ACTOR the probability that they recognize their role correctly is..."*, where for all the actors the probabilities are the same, and equal to $p(\oplus|\mathsf{actor}) = 0.7$. If you ask three random people to identify the role, assuming that they are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) (e.g. you asked them separately), the probability that the first two of them were correct and the third is wrong is

$$
p(\oplus_1, \oplus_2, \ominus_3 | EW) = p(\oplus_1 | EW)\,p(\oplus_2 | EW)\,p(\ominus_3 | EW) = 0.7 \times 0.7 \times 0.3 = 0.147
$$

and for the scenario where the minority is correct, it is

$$
p(\ominus_1, \ominus_2, \oplus_3 | EW) = p(\ominus_1 | EW)\,p(\ominus_2 | EW)\,p(\oplus_3 | EW) = 0.3 \times 0.3 \times 0.7 = 0.063
$$

and is the same for all the actors. This is pretty straightforward because you know that someone can be either correct or wrong, so you care about the majority being correct or wrong. If you didn't have the majority, with the information you have (equal probabilities), you wouldn't be able to tell.